# R - efficiently loop through matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply

I have a matrix (named "my_matrix") with 150 columns (colnames are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...) and 100000 rows.

I perform the following operation:

```
missing = c(50,57,60,77,99,101,102,109)

for(i in 1:ncol(my_matrix)) {
  if(colnames(my_matrix)[i] %in% missing) {
    for(j in 1:nrow(my_matrix)) {
        if(grepl('_old$', rownames(my_matrix)[j])){
          my_matrix[j,i] <- my_matrix[gsub("_old", "_new", rownames(my_matrix)[j]),i]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This operation works fine, and basically looks if the name of the column is found in "missing". If so, it looks whether the name of the row ends with "_old". If so, the value of the cell is replaced with the value of another cell (e.g. the value of column 50 & row 237478_old is replaced with the value of column 50 & row 237478_new and so on).

Unfortunately it is very slow and takes hours until the execution is finished. Is there any faster way to perform this operation (e.g. with apply)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create the index of the columns ('j1') and the rows (for both the 'new' and 'old' row names), and extract the values with row/column indexing and replace with the values from the "new" row/column values.

```
 j1 <- colnames(my_matrix) %in% missing
 i1 <- grepl('_old$', rownames(my_matrix))
 i2 <- grepl('_new$', rownames(my_matrix))
 my_matrix[i1,j1] <- my_matrix(i2, j1]
```

Comment: You've got some typos; `mymatrix` vs `my_matrix`, parenthesis in the last line.

Comment: As is so often the case, the right answer to the numerous novice questions on "how to efficiently loop" in R is rather simply to avoid performing the loop.

Comment: Just curious, does anyone know why it seems to be faster to do this in 4 lines than substituting into 1? Even leaving `j1` as is so it doesn't get calculated twice, it's still a hint faster in 4.